# Crash on iOS > TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.8

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, crash, privacy

I've got an error in my app (iOS 8 to iOS 11) :

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1839a00a8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18399b100 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18399b12c system_set_sfi_window + 10
3  TCC                            0x1868ed99c __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.85 + 222
4  TCC                            0x1868ed8bc __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 706
5  TCC                            0x1868f113c __tccd_send_block_invoke + 316
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x183aeda0c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 60
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x183aed948 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 88
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18380d758 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x183825060 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 324
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x183813f54 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 400
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18381a1c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 596
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x183819f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183ab3130 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183ab2c30 start_wqthread + 4
```

I've read some subjects about errors like this one. Each time, people says that comes from Permissions in infos.plist.

App uses camera, library, geolocation. So I add :
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Privacy - Location When in Use
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

But there is always the same problem.

I add Microphone usage in plist, but same crash occurs.

I don't understand the crash. On my iPhone, everything works perfectly but on some devices, this error cause crashes. Could you help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you are trying to use something even if user declined access for app

Comment: Indeed, there was a lack of authorization. The application offers to save images in the user's library and it was missing: NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Comment: Thanks @kopacabana it saved my time :)

Comment: As mentioned by @kopacabana this is a lack of authorization. in my case the FaceID permission was missing, so it crashed on all FaceID-Devices.

Comment: May be it will help you.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679078/tcc-tccaccessrequest-block-invoke

Answer (score 8):

Check all of your `WKWebView` that is are loading images.
If you long press on Webview it shows an option to save photos in app.

Fix for the crash:

```
webView?.allowsLinkPreview = false
```