# TCC __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, privacy

I'm getting this error frequently in Crashlytics.

```
TCC __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 222
TCC __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 682
```

In my app i'm downloading images and stored that images in photo gallery directly, i'm not creating suppurate folder to store these images. For this in plist i added access permission.

```
Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description - Save downloaded photos in gallary
Privacy - Camera Usage Description - This app not access your Camera
Privacy - Microphone Usage Description - This app not access your Microphone
```

But i'm getting lot of crashes. See the below screen shot....

[image]

Can any one help me...

Comment: Are you using Google Analytics? I see GAIThread on there. I suddenly started getting a lot of crashes in the last week or so too. Wondering if it is Google Analytics related.

Comment: @Skyler Lauren Yes, i'm using google analytics in my app and i'm tracking all screens. Can you explain me briefly about this. I'm getting lot of errors in Fabric, out of all this is the major one. Can you help me to solve these errors...

Comment: Is your app live? Was it fine and now just starting to show these in the last couple of weeks? That is the case when my app. I suspect in my case an iOS update is causing an issue but Xcode just gives me 11.2 not the minor update. I updated my firebase analytics to see if that helps. I was several versions behind on that.

Comment: My app is in live, and I updated my app so many times. Now crashlytics released new version, so I updated my app with in few days. I think I am expecting for permission to access gallery we need to mention two types of permissions for iOS 11 and below that. I will update my app completely, after that I will check one more time. Can u keep in touch for me

Comment: I have updated my app with the latest version of Firebase and I am still getting those crashes, =/ Also my app does ask permissions to access the camera roll too. I have tested and tested denying access, giving access, and even removing access after the fact and no crashes. Are all these crashes iOS 11 for you and do you know exactly what iOS 11.x.x version it is mine are all 11.2.5.

Comment: @ Skyler Lauren Ok, me also will inform to you when I update my app.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 23):

Ok this has been driving me nuts for the last couple of weeks. In my case I was missing: `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` Which is apparently needed if the user tries to use the "save to camera roll" in the share controller. This appears to be new to iOS 11.

I already had this

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

Which I used when user wanted to import. This gives me read/write permissions. However if the user went to export and used share controller prior to importing it would crash the app if `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` wasn't in the plist. Hopefully this helps you and if not someone else.

Answer (score 8):

Do you really need to save the photos?
If yes, the above answer works.

But if you have an app like mine which should NOT ALLOW user to save photos and the app still is crashing, then

Check all of your `WKWebView` that is are loading images.
If you long press on Webview it shows an option to save photos in app.

Fix for the crash:

```
webView?.allowsLinkPreview = false
```

Comment: @iOS  image loading on `WKWebview` was crashing the app for you ?

Comment: This is unbelievable! Thanks!